# How to iterate over a list of certain data types while accessing of the the elements of that data type

Tags: loops, haskell

On [code.world/haskell (see the full code)](https://code.world/haskell#PMS1C91vi1SxA18OTCVCVOQ), I have the following data types

```
data Lattice = Lattice
  {
    latPos :: (Double, Double),
    occupied :: Bool
  }

data Ant = Ant
  {
    antPos :: Point,
    bagFilled :: Bool
  }


data World = World
  {
    ants :: Ant,
    space :: [Lattice]
  }
```

And, inside `renderWorld` function, I am creating a list of `Lattices`. Then, I want to iterate over this list while applying the function `f` like this

```
renderWorld :: World -> Picture
renderWorld w = foldl (<>) (translated 0 0 $ rectangle 0 0) lattices
  where
    f :: Lattice -> Picture
    f lat = do
      let pos :: (Double, Double)
          pos = (latPos lat)
      if pos == (_,5) then translated pos $ solidRectangle latticeSize latticeSize
       else translated $ pos $ rectangle latticeSize latticeSize
    lattices = map f (space w)
```

But for some reason, it gives me the following error

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Picture’ with actual type ‘Picture ->
>   Picture’

What am I doing wrong exactly? I couldn't figure out for the last 2 hours.

Comment: your full error message should include line number or some other indication of the error's location.

Comment: @WillNess yes, it is on the line starting with `if pos == (_,5)` but I can't understand why it is wrong, and how to correct it

Comment: according to the rules of SO full relevant error message must be included in the question body. why should we be guessing?

Comment: @WillNess First of all, you can see the whole error (1 page long) by just running the code on the link (just press 'Run'). Secondly, I have already put the main part of the error into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `translated` is:

```
translated :: Double -> Double -> Picture -> Picture
```

In particular, `translated` takes three arguments to produce a `Picture`, but you only gave it two.

```
translated pos $ solidRectangle latticeSize latticeSize
```

You are passing coordinates as a pair `pos`, whereas they are expected to be passed separately:

```
let (xpos, ypos) = latPos lat
if ... then translated xpos ypos $ solidRectangle latticeSize latticeSize
```

Furthermore, in the `else` branch there is an extra `$` which changes how things are associated:

```
translated $ pos $ rectangle latticeSize latticeSize
-- This is `translated` applied to one argument:
translated (pos (rectangle latticSize latticeSize))
```

Finally in the `if` you have a pattern, which is invalid syntax (between `if` and `then` there should be an expression):

```
if pos == (_, 5) then ...
else ...
```

In this case since it's preferable to deconstruct the pair anyway, you can instead write

```
if ypos == 5 then ...
else ...
```

But otherwise you could also have written this using `case`:

```
case pos of      -- "if"
  (_, 5) -> ...  -- "then"
  _ -> ...       -- "else"
```

After fixing those errors:

```
  where
    f :: Lattice -> Picture
    f lat = do
      let xpos, ypos :: Double
          (xpos, ypos) = (latPos lat)
      if ypos == 5 then translated xpos ypos $ solidRectangle latticeSize latticeSize
       else translated xpos ypos $ rectangle latticeSize latticeSize
    lattices = map f (space w)
```

Full code: https://code.world/haskell#PS44YI3JbKZc5JWvLqGRKSA